# Minimal Real World Computer Specs for Reason 6 on Windows

Tags: hardware, windows

This is a question for PC users of Reason 6.

I have a Mac-based production studio, and I run a multitude of applications on a high end Mac Pro. I've decided to create a second workstation based solely around Propellerheads Reason 6. I haven't built a Windows PC in so long that I'm having trouble discerning the real-world differences among i3, i5, and i7 processors in terms of track count and robustness.

I know that this is a loaded question with only the hope of anecdotal answers, but that's exactly what I am looking for. What processor has worked for you where you feel comfortable? Let's say 32-48 tracks of audio with 40 instruments max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your budget is, but I would recommend these specs:

1. You have a choice between the [i5 2500k](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819115072) and the i7 2600k. The i5 is cheaper than the i7 and comes close in performance.
2. Between 8 and 16 GB of DDR3.
3. A dedicated sound card.
4. If you are building this computer yourself, a good motherboard is always a necessity. I would recommend checking out [this article about MOSFETS](http://www.overclock.net/t/943109/about-vrms-mosfets-motherboard-safety-with-125w-tdp-processors) and [this article](http://www.overclock.net/t/946407/amd-motherboard-vrm-information-list) to make sure you have a motherboard that can handle your i5, but with a quad-core, it's not as big of deal as a 125W 6-core.

Please note I have not used Logic much, but I would imagine a computer with these specs would run it fine.